Co-domain and range of composite functions
if we define a composite function, say fog, between 2 arbitrary functions f and g (assuming that range of g is a subset of domain of f) then can we say that the co domain of fog = co domain of f ? and in general can we say that in a composite function of 2 functions, the co domain of the composite function is same as the co domain of the former function (like f in fog, h in hof etc.) ?
and for range can we say that the range of a composite function between 2 functions (like fog between f and g, hof between h and f) is the subset of the range of the former function  (like f in fog, h in hof etc.) ?
